# Grant access to previous public research results including IPR for the purpose of future commercial exploitation

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software, open-source-software, research

We are building a project of technology transfer.

In the project, one partner is a university XXX; the main contact person who will work with us is a professor. Previously, the professor and his team at University XXX carried out a research project and had some interesting results (abbreviated as RRR), which were all publicly published with articles and open-source software (permissive MIT expat license).
In the envisioned project,
we are going to combine their results and our previous results, and advance them together.

In the envisioned project, a startup YYY will be the sole company that undertakes the commercial exploitation.

So my question is, do we need any official agreements from University XXX to say that they grant the startup YYY access to the previous research results RRR including IPR
for the purpose of future commercial exploitation?

Comment: Will the professor provide information beyond what was published? What does the professor’s contract with the university say about IP? What does the funding source for the university project  require ?

Comment: (1) The professor will participate in the envisioned project and make contributions. (2) The university has not claimed any interest in commercializing the previous results. (3) The funding source was purely for research, and did not say anything about IP.